# Manually giving input and output for QGIS graphical modeler exported python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I am using QGIS 3.

How could I manually give the input layer and the output path to the following script extracted from the graphical modeler?

It is a simple model, it takes a DEM as input and apply the hillshade.

'''

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('input', 'input', defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination('Output', 'output', createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    # Sombreamento
    alg_params = {
        'AZIMUTH': 300,
        'INPUT': parameters['input'],
        'V_ANGLE': 40,
        'Z_FACTOR': 1,
        'OUTPUT': parameters['Output']
    }
    outputs['Sombreamento'] = processing.run('qgis:hillshade', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Output'] = outputs['Sombreamento']['OUTPUT']
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'modelo'

def displayName(self):
    return 'modelo'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Modelo()
```

'''

Comment: Run it once from the model GUI. Go to `Processing --> History`. See how QGIS passed those parameters to the model. That's how you could pass them to your Python script.

Comment: I did not understand the reason for defining the paths. Would you like the input and output to be the same each time? without the user defining them?